# Using multiprocessing for finding network paths

Tags: python, multiprocessing, threadpool, networkx

I am currently using the networkx function *all_simple_paths* to find all paths within a network G, for a given set of source and target nodes.

On larger/denser networks this process is incredibly intensive.

I would like to know if multiprocessing could conceivably be used on this problem, and if anybody had any ideas on how that might be implemented, through creating a Pool etc.

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.complete_graph(8)
sources = [1,2]
targets = [5,6,7]

for target in targets:
    for source in sources:
        for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, source=source, target=target, cutoff=None):
            print(path)
```

Many thanks in advance for any suggestions you may have!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a version which uses a collection of worker processes. Each worker gets `source, target` pairs from a Queue, and collects the paths in a list. When all the paths have been found, the results are put in an output Queue, and collated by the main process.

```
import networkx as nx
import multiprocessing as mp
import random
import sys
import itertools as IT
import logging
logger = mp.log_to_stderr(logging.DEBUG)


def worker(inqueue, output):
    result = []
    count = 0
    for pair in iter(inqueue.get, sentinel):
        source, target = pair
        for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, source = source, target = target,
                                        cutoff = None):
            result.append(path)
            count += 1
            if count % 10 == 0:
                logger.info('{c}'.format(c = count))
    output.put(result)

def test_workers():
    result = []
    inqueue = mp.Queue()
    for source, target in IT.product(sources, targets):
        inqueue.put((source, target))
    procs = [mp.Process(target = worker, args = (inqueue, output))
             for i in range(mp.cpu_count())]
    for proc in procs:
        proc.daemon = True
        proc.start()
    for proc in procs:    
        inqueue.put(sentinel)
    for proc in procs:
        result.extend(output.get())
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
    return result

def test_single_worker():
    result = []
    count = 0
    for source, target in IT.product(sources, targets):
        for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, source = source, target = target,
                                        cutoff = None):
            result.append(path)
            count += 1
            if count % 10 == 0:
                logger.info('{c}'.format(c = count))

    return result

sentinel = None

seed = 1
m = 1
N = 1340//m
G = nx.gnm_random_graph(N, int(1.7*N), seed)
random.seed(seed)
sources = [random.randrange(N) for i in range(340//m)]
targets = [random.randrange(N) for i in range(1000//m)]
output = mp.Queue()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_workers()
    # test_single_worker()
    # assert set(map(tuple, test_workers())) == set(map(tuple, test_single_worker()))
```

`test_workers` uses multiprocessing, `test_single_worker` uses a single process.

Running `test.py` does not raise an AssertionError, so it looks like both functions return the same result (at least for the limited tests I've run).

Here are the timeit results:

```
% python -mtimeit -s'import test as t' 't.test_workers()'
10 loops, best of 3: 6.71 sec per loop

% python -mtimeit -s'import test as t' 't.test_single_worker()'
10 loops, best of 3: 12.2 sec per loop
```

So test_workers was able to achieve a 1.8x speedup over test_single_worker on a 2-core system in this case. Hopefully, the code will scale well for your real problem too. I'd be interested to know the result.

---

Some points of interest:

- Calling `pool.apply_async` on a short-lived function is very slow,
  because too much time is spent passing arguments in, and results out
  through queues rather than using the CPUs to do useful computation.
- It is better to collect results in a list and put the full result in
  the `output` Queue rather than putting results in `output` one at a
  time. Each object put in the Queue is pickled, and it is quicker to
  pickle one large list than it is many small lists.
- I think it is safer to print from only one process, so the print
  statements do not step on each other (resulting in mangled output).

Comment: Unutbu, many thanks for your suggestions. The code completed, and returned the expected path set. it did however do this (for a given network with 340 source and 1000 target nodes) in a time of  2039s compared to a time of 79s (that was achieved with my original code). Do you have any ideas on how this time might be reduced - it is my intuition that it is the iteration over targets/sources that would benefit from the multiprocessing the most - but as you suggested there may be problems with stepping -- do you have any ideas for other control structures that may remedy this? Cheers.

Comment: my actual code is as stated above in the original post - the only difference is that my network consists of (1340 nodes), and is relatively sparse (not of the complete type) -- of which 340 nodes are source and 1000 are target.

Comment: Many thanks for the updates - the code works well, and both functions return the same sets for a range of set-ups. There is also a considerable speedup (using a 4-core system). One problem is that for larger graphs (for my own data) or with your graph when m is less than 4, the code does not run! in order to speed up completion of the paths I have implemented a cutoff of 5(or other similar value -- although this is not necessary). I am not sure why this is happening. Have you any ideas? and do you face the same problem on your machine? perhaps there is a need to implement sleep!? Cheers

Comment: @scott_ouce: I've added some logging statements to the code. It shows that it does indeed find paths even when `m` is 1. Maybe try adding some logging when you run the code on your real data to find out where the code is hanging.

Comment: [DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 5
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 6
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 7
[DEBUG/MainProcess] Queue._after_fork()
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 10
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 11
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 12
[DEBUG/MainProcess] Queue._after_fork()
[DEBUG/MainProcess] Queue._start_thread()
[DEBUG/MainProcess] doing self._thread.start()
[DEBUG/MainProcess] starting thread to feed data to pipe
[DEBUG/MainProcess] ... done self._thread.start()
hanging here!,cheers

Comment: How much memory is the process consuming? And what OS are you using?

Comment: using Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5 -- python 2.7 -- i am not sure exactly how much memory is consumed, (unscientifically; nothing really spikes on the mac activity monitor), can you recommend another way to test the consumption?

Comment: So -- just to be sure -- with the code I posted above, with `m = 5`, the code runs, but with `m = 4`, the code hangs? Do both the `test_workers` and `test_single_worker` function hang?

Comment: when m = 4 the code runs, but when m <= 3 it hangs. test_single_worker works fine for all values of m and all networks that I have tested. so only the test_workers function hangs

Comment: Ug. I'm sorry. I have no idea why that is happening. I could suggest extra logging statements to try to pinpoint the line where it is hanging, but I do not want to lead you on a long goose chase when I'm not confident I know the answer.

Comment: that's ok -- many thanks for all of your help and advice! I will try running it on a different machine, and look further into why it is not running on this one.. best wishes,

Comment: Okay, if you find out the source of the problem, please let me know. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

For the simplest case it appears that your paths have no relations to each other, other than being part of the same graph, so there would not be any locking issues.

What I would do is you can use the `multiprocessing` module to start a new process on each loop over the `targets` using a `Pool` and the `map` method.

```
def create_graph_from_target( target )
    for source in sources:
        for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, source=source, target=target, cutoff=None):
            print(path)

from multiprocessing import Pool
p = Pool( processes=4 )

p.map( create_graph_from_target, targets )
p.close()
p.join()
```

Comment: Sean, many thanks for your suggestion. When implementing your code I lost a number of paths, and a number of paths were unexpected (not found in the true set of paths) - for example (for a given network, source, and target set) I expect 7616 paths.. running your code generates for 1processes 7578,4processes 7233, and 8processes 7055 paths. each time I run your code the number of paths changes. Have you any idea why this may be happening? Perhaps it has to do with @unutbu comment, that the print statements are stepping on each other!?

Comment: in addition --The idea of starting a process on each loop of the targets seems good though - as I have on average 4 times as many targets to sinks -- and although continuity was not maintained the code ran in 19s compared to 79s (for a given setup), which is more like what I am looking for!

Comment: Hmm, I may need to look into that as the number of results should not go down as you have seen. The print mangling might at the root of the issue. I would also use some kind of list or queue to college t the results.

Comment: I have not yet implemented a queue, but this does indeed seem to be the best solution! I will try that and let you know how I get on, cheers,