# python multiprocessing hanging, potential queue memory error?

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I recently posted a question [Using multiprocessing for finding network paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993674/using-multiprocessing-for-finding-network-paths) and was pleased to have been offered a neat solution by @unutbu

I have however run into difficulties when executing the `test_workers()` (utilising multiprocessing) function. The code runs, but hangs with large numbers of nodes `N` in my network `G`

Running using Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5 -- python 2.7, it hangs when N>500. logging brings the following messages, after which it hangs

```
[DEBUG/MainProcess] doing self._thread.start()
[DEBUG/MainProcess] starting thread to feed data to pipe
[DEBUG/MainProcess] ... done self._thread.start()
```

Running on windows 7 through VMware fusion facilitates larger networks, but eventually hangs with graphs around where N> 20,000 nodes (I would ideally like to use this on networks up to N = 500,000). Message from the windows side at point of hanging:

```
[DEBUG/MainProcess] starting thread to feed data to pipe
[DEBUG/MainProcess] ... done self._thread.start()[DEBUG/MainProcess] telling queue thread to quit
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Scott\Desktop\fp_test.py", line 75, in <module>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 264, in _feed
    test_workers()
    MemoryError
```

I wondered if anybody had any ideas as to why this is happening? and if there are any suggestions of how to get this working for larger networks?

Many thanks in advance for any suggestions that you may have.

@unutbu's code:

```
import networkx as nx
import multiprocessing as mp
import random
import sys
import itertools as IT
import logging
logger = mp.log_to_stderr(logging.DEBUG)


def worker(inqueue, output):
    result = []
    count = 0
    for pair in iter(inqueue.get, sentinel):
        source, target = pair
        for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, source = source, target = target,
                                        cutoff = None):
            result.append(path)
            count += 1
            if count % 10 == 0:
                logger.info('{c}'.format(c = count))
    output.put(result)

def test_workers():
    result = []
    inqueue = mp.Queue()
    for source, target in IT.product(sources, targets):
        inqueue.put((source, target))
    procs = [mp.Process(target = worker, args = (inqueue, output))
             for i in range(mp.cpu_count())]
    for proc in procs:
        proc.daemon = True
        proc.start()
    for proc in procs:    
        inqueue.put(sentinel)
    for proc in procs:
        result.extend(output.get())
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
    return result

def test_single_worker():
    result = []
    count = 0
    for source, target in IT.product(sources, targets):
        for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, source = source, target = target,
                                        cutoff = None):
            result.append(path)
            count += 1
            if count % 10 == 0:
                logger.info('{c}'.format(c = count))

    return result

sentinel = None

seed = 1
m = 1
N = 1340//m
G = nx.gnm_random_graph(N, int(1.7*N), seed)
random.seed(seed)
sources = [random.randrange(N) for i in range(340//m)]
targets = [random.randrange(N) for i in range(1000//m)]
output = mp.Queue()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_workers()
    # test_single_worker()
    # assert set(map(tuple, test_workers())) == set(map(tuple, test_single_worker()))
```

Answer (score 2):

You came across a deadlock with the `logging` module.

This module keeps some thread locks to allow safe logging across threads, but it does not play well when the current process is forked. See for example [here](http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them) for an explanation of what's going on.

The solution is to remove the `logging` calls or use plain `print`s instead.

Anyway, as a general rule, avoid using threads + forking. And always check which modules use threads behind the scenes.

Note that on windows it works simply because windows does not have `fork` and thus does not have the problem of lock-cloning with the subsequent deadlock.
In that case the `MemoryError` indicates that the process is consuming too much RAM.
You'll probably have to rethink the algorithm to use less RAM, but it's completely different from the problem you are having on OSX

Comment: Having removed the logging calls I still find the code hanging on OSX. Do you think any of the other modules are keeping threads locked? (and how might i find that out?) - in addition; do you know if there is a limit to the size of the queue i am using?

Comment: @scott_ouce Searching a bit I found this [issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue7200) in `multiprocessing`'s issue tracked. It may be related to your problem since it relates to both MacOSX and `mp.Queue`.
Anyway it seems really strange to me, since I don't see a possible weakref problem in your code.